Sharing the same price scale for both left and right in lightweight charts

I am drawing some lines to visualize the time of long/short position. 
My goal is to position label (P&L text) **to the left border of the chart**.
const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
  layout: {
    background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: 'transparent' },
    textColor: '#333',
  },
  grid: {
    vertLines: { color: '#444' },
    horzLines: { color: '#444' },
  },
  width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth,
  height: 400,
  timeScale: {
    timeVisible: true,
    secondsVisible: false,
  },
});


// Create order line
const orderLine = chart.addLineSeries({
  color: trade.action === 'LONG' ? '#26a69a' : '#ef5350',
  lineWidth: 2,
  lineStyle: LineStyle.Solid,
  title: `PnL:${pnl?.toFixed(4)}`,
  priceScaleId: 'left',
});

Setting priceScaleId to left does a trick, but the problem is, left and right have different price scales. 
This results in lines being drawn lower or higher than its original position. 
How can I have the same price scaling for both left and right, or is there any other solution?
Appreciate your help!

